# How to explode two array column in scala dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[image]

if i just do below, i get 4 rows mark getting repeated for each subject. Can anyone give a pointer here to solve this.

```
df.withColumn("subject", explode($"subject")).withColumn("mark", explode($"mark"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `arrays_zip` to zip both arrays and `inline` to inline explode array column values.

You can also `inline` or `inline_outer` functions

```
df
.select(
   $"name", 
   inline(
      arrays_zip(
        $"subject", 
        $"mark"
      )
   )
)
.show(false)
```

```
+----+-------+----+
|name|subject|mark|
+----+-------+----+
|abc |math   |40  |
|abc |english|50  |
+----+-------+----+
```

OR

You can also use `explode_outer` or `explode` functions

```
df
.withColumn(
     "zip", 
     explode_outer(
        arrays_zip(
           $"subject", 
           $"mark"
        )
     )
)
.select(
    $"name", 
    $"zip.*"
)
.show(false)
```

Comment: error: not found: value inline . what is the module i need to import to user inline?

Comment: which spark version you are using ?

Comment: 3.1.2 is the version name

Comment: `inline` function should be available in org.apache.spark.sql.functions package.